# How to generate a list of IP addresses between two addresses with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ip-address

I have a user input a string of IP addresses they'd like to use. That string looks something like:

```
192.168.1.3-192.168.1.100
```

I'm trying to generate an array of IP addresses including, and between the start and end address, which would look something like:

```
["192.168.1.3","192.168.1.4",.....,"192.168.1.99","192.168.1.100"]
```

I was hoping it would be as simple as

```
("192.168.1.3".."192.168.1.100").step(1).to_a
```

but I guess it isn't.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
 and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [IPAddr](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) from the Ruby Stdlib.

> IPAddr provides a set of methods to manipulate an IP address. Both
>   IPv4 and IPv6 are supported.

```
require 'ipaddr'

# I used a smaller number to limit the output
ip_range = IPAddr.new("192.168.1.3")..IPAddr.new("192.168.1.13")
ip_range.to_a
```

The output is an array of IPAddr instances.

```
=> [#<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.1.3/255.255.255.255>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.1.4/255.255.255.255>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.1.5/255.255.255.255>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.1.6/255.255.255.255>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.1.7/255.255.255.255>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.1.8/255.255.255.255>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.1.9/255.255.255.255>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.1.10/255.255.255.255>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.1.11/255.255.255.255>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.1.12/255.255.255.255>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.1.13/255.255.255.255>]
```

A word of warning though. If you are taking user input make sure to catch the potential `IPAddr::InvalidAddressError` that can occur.

```
begin 
  IPAddr.new(params[:from])..IPAddr.new(params[:to])
rescue IPAddr::InvalidAddressError
  # @todo handle error
  logger.info("Oh Noes!")
end
```

Comment: @Godzilla74: The trick here is that Ruby is an object-oriented language, not a string-oriented language. You can pretty much always make any task much easier by modeling your problem with rich, structured, domain objects instead of anemic, unstructured strings. Strings don't know about subnets, IP addresses, etc. but `IPAddr`s do.

Comment: @JörgWMittag TIL That string oriented languages actually are (where?) a thing.

Answer (score 3):

[IPAddress](https://github.com/ipaddress-gem/ipaddress) is a very powerful gem, much more powerful that Ruby's built-in IPAddr, which handles all sorts of networking and subnetting tasks and understands IPv4 and IPv6.

```
require 'ipaddress'

ip = IPAddress('192.168.0.1')
ip.to('192.168.0.5')
# => ["192.168.0.1",
#     "192.168.0.2",
#     "192.168.0.3",
#     "192.168.0.4",
#     "192.168.0.5"]
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
IPAddress('192.168.0.1').to('192.168.0.5')
# => ["192.168.0.1",
#     "192.168.0.2",
#     "192.168.0.3",
#     "192.168.0.4",
#     "192.168.0.5"]
```

I used it for some pretty cool automation in huge routing tables.